# The react component product which shows the details of the products doesnt render anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React , {useContext} from 'react'
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import RemoveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Remove';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import axios from 'axios'
//import {ids} from "./Scanner"

let ids=[{productid:'9501101530003'}]
const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#1A2027' : '#fff',
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));
const Item2 = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#1A2027' : '#fff',
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(2.5),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));
export default function Cart (){
  console.log(ids)
  let products = []
  
  ids.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element)
    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/barcode',element)
    .then((response)=>{
      console.log(response)
      products.push(response.data.product)
      console.log(products)
    })
    });

          function Product ({product}){
            console.log("g")
               console.log(product)
              return(  <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
              <Grid container rowSpacing={1} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                  <Item2>{props.product.productName}</Item2>
                </Grid> 
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                  <Item2>2</Item2>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4} >
                  <Item> 
                     <IconButton color="primary">
                  <AddIcon fontSize='small'/>
                    </IconButton>
                    3
                  <IconButton   color="primary">
                  <RemoveIcon fontSize='small'/>
                    </IconButton>
                  </Item>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Box>
              )
          }
    return(
        <div >
             <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
              <Grid container rowSpacing={1} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                  <Item>product name</Item>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                  <Item>price</Item>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                  <Item>
                      quantity
                   </Item>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Box>
            {products.forEach(element => {
              <Product product={element} />
            })}
            <Box sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
              <Grid container rowSpacing={1} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }}  justifyContent="center"
                 alignItems="center" >
                <Grid item xs={4}>
                  <Item>total</Item>
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Box>
            <div>
            <Button href='/payment'>pay</Button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The requesr using axios returns details of the products . and add that object into the products array. I want render the datails of each and every product using the product component.but the product component doesnt render anything . it dosn't consolelog the g . please help me
everything else seems to work fine.

Comment: replace `forEach` with `map`

Comment: still it doesn't render anything

Comment: now I've looked more closely, I see why it doesn't - you're declaring `products` at the top level of your function and then populating it from within your axios request. This isn't going to work because `products` will be the empty array on each render. You'll need to make the request in a `useEffect` and use state for the products array - there are examples of this sort of thing everywhere.

Comment: I hope this is what you meant `  const [product,setproduct] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    ids.forEach(element => { 
      console.log(element)
      axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/barcode',element)  
      .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response)  
  newproduct= product 
  newproduct.push(response.data.product)
  setproduct(newproduct)
  console.log(product)      
      })
      });
  })`

Comment: but it shows the products only after I re run the program not the first time. please help @RobinZigmond

Comment: yes, that's how asynchronous code works. If it breaks your UI you can always show a loading indicator of some sort until you have the products data.

Comment: but when I navigate to this cart page from another page it shows no products . according to what you said if I wait for some time it must show the products right but it doesn't.

Comment: well then your component code must be wrong in some way - either that or there's something up with your backend API. Either way this is now very different from your first question so I suggest you start a new question, showing your latest code.

Answer (score 0):

Change `{products.forEach(element => {<Product product={element} />})}` to:

```
products.map((element,index)=>(<Product key={index} product={element} />)
```

Because **forEach** does not return anything